# Tomcat cluster fails and generates tons of logs

Tags: tomcat6

Periodically, I'm getting problems with my Tomcat 6 cluster (2 nodes). One of the nodes would just go haywire and generate a ton of logs repeating the following:

```
Aug 25, 2009 11:44:10 AM org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaRequest reset
SEVERE: Unable to remove element
java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.LinkedList.remove(LinkedList.java:788)
        at java.util.LinkedList.removeFirst(LinkedList.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaRequest.reset(DeltaRequest.java:201)
        at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaRequest.execute(DeltaRequest.java:195)
        at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager.handleSESSION_DELTA(DeltaManager.java:1364)
        at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager.messageReceived(DeltaManager.java:1320)
        at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager.messageDataReceived(DeltaManager.java:1083)
        at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener.messageReceived(ClusterSessionListener.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster.messageReceived(SimpleTcpCluster.java:916)
        at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster.messageReceived(SimpleTcpCluster.java:897)
        at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel.messageReceived(GroupChannel.java:264)
        at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.ChannelInterceptorBase.messageReceived(ChannelInterceptorBase.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector.messageReceived(TcpFailureDetector.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.ChannelInterceptorBase.messageReceived(ChannelInterceptorBase.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.ChannelInterceptorBase.messageReceived(ChannelInterceptorBase.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.ChannelInterceptorBase.messageReceived(ChannelInterceptorBase.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.ChannelCoordinator.messageReceived(ChannelCoordinator.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReceiverBase.messageDataReceived(ReceiverBase.java:225)
        at org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReplicationTask.drainChannel(NioReplicationTask.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReplicationTask.run(NioReplicationTask.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

That's the only thing that it shows. The other node in the cluster is still active at this time. There's nothing to do but to restart. The large amount of logs has caused disk space issues more than a couple of times too.

Does anybody have any idea what's wrong here?

Thanks!
Wong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be a bug in Tomcat 6. If you look at the source at:

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Sevlet-Container/apache-tomcat-6.0.14/org/apache/catalina/ha/session/DeltaRequest.java.htm (line 225)

you'll see that the reset() method can potentially throw this exception. I suggest that you contact the Tomcat developers regarding this issue.